# What oauth 2.0 endpoint is used to validate a bearer token

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-oauth, django-oauth-toolkit

I have an oauth 2 server implemented using django oauth2 provider.

I am implementing the client credentials flow in an api.

The client app POSTs to the oauth server's /token/ endpoint to get the access token. That is then sent to my api in the header. What endpoint should the api then call on the oauth server to validate this token, when using a back channel?

[image]